# flavoured resources in android

Tags: android, resources, android-productflavors

I am developing an app and now I want to flavour it.
I managed to add flavours into the app module but I don't know how or if it is possible to have the same flavours in other modules. 
Bellow you can see the structure of my code:

```
-> app
   ---> res
       ---> values
           ---> flavour1/layout
           ---> flavour2/layout
-> ux
   ---> res
       ---> values
           ---> colors
          // I want to have the following res
           ---> flavour1/colors
           ---> flavour2/colors
```

Trying to add falvour1/res/values/colors.xml and flavour2/res/values/colors.xml to the ux/src did not help. I think I need make dependencies work throughout the application as this [suggests](https://android.jlelse.eu/product-flavors-for-android-library-d3b2d240fca2)